# Where can I find the teddy bear?

Tags: dead-island

I have a quest to find a lost teddy bear for a girl who has trouble sleeping (possibly due to all the zombies walking), but I can't seem to find it.  Can someone post a map pointing to the location of the lost teddy bear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the reason why the quest wasn't tracking was because I was too far away.

The bungalows Anne was talking about is way back near the hotel the blue waypoint in this map is where it is located:

[image]